# Dart Singleton with parameters (global app logger)

Tags: flutter, dart, logging, singleton, global

I'd like to use the [Logger](https://pub.dev/packages/logger) library in my app. I only want to instantiate it once so that I have consistent formatting across my app. Also I would like to avoid instantiating `PrettyPrinter()` several times :

```
// Where should I put this ?
var logger = Logger(
  printer: PrettyPrinter(
    methodCount: 2,
    colors: true,
  ),
);
```

What is the right way of doing this?
Should I just use a global const? Is there a way to do this using a Singleton?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I prefer to use a **Singleton**.

This is not a common pattern in Flutter, but it is very meaningful to choose it in this scenario. The logger must be accessed everywhere, without any context. And it is okay to keep it alive until the end of the application's life.

My recommendation is to create a file `log.dart` containing this :

```
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';
Logger get logger => Log.instance;

class Log extends Logger {
  Log._() : super(printer: PrettyPrinter(printTime: true));
  static final instance = Log._();
}
```

Then, you can access your logger anywhere with :

```
logger.d('My debug message');
```

Comment: Thank you (for the answer and the edits!). You say this is not a common pattern in Flutter, could you recommend a solution that is a right Flutter/Dart pattern?

Comment: Thanks for showing your version. I like having the `className` in the log entries, so each class gets its own logger.

Comment: I was just saying that it is not common, I am not saying that we should never use Singletons in Flutter/Dart. In that case, I believe it is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

I define a helper function to get the Logger:

```dart
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';
import 'log_printer.dart';

Logger getLogger(String className) {
  return Logger(printer: SimpleLogPrinter(className));
}
```

Then in each class where I want logging for eaxmple:

```dart
class ProfileService with ChangeNotifier {
  static final _log = getLogger('ProfileService');

  Future<Profile> updateProfile(Profile profile) async {
    _log.v('updateProfile');
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Another example:

```dart
class AuthScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final log = getLogger('AuthScreen');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    log.v('build called');
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Good answer ! I would however rename `getLogger` by `createLogger` because it is doesn't belong to any class, it is instanciated each time the method is called

Comment: The caller does not know if a new logger is created or not, so I prefer `getLogger`.

Comment: In responding to comments I realised I did not include the class `SimpleLogPrinter`. In researching it I found this Medium post by the original author, who I should have credited before! https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-guide-to-setting-up-better-logging-in-flutter-3db8bab2000e